# How to load panoroma 360 degree image from url in my android application?

Tags: android, panoramas

Explanation: I am new to android. I don't know how to load panorama image in my android application.I tried more it's loaded from the drawable folder. But, i want to load it from the url to my android application.

Many of people suggest me to use panoramaGl ready-mate library. i tried this libraries too but not gave the output as much i expected.

Please, help me what is the best solution to load panorama image from url and load into my android application.

Answer (score 0):

```
Kindly refer, it may help
```

[PanoramaImageView](http://%20https://github.com/gjiazhe/PanoramaImageView) Library with guidance in Android App

Another option is to use [Panoramagl-android library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/panoramagl-android/)